# How to find the number of a specific entry for each column in my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables in my HTML file.  I want to generate some statistic from myTable into summaryTable. I want the total number of tests[in column 1], total number of "Success"[in column 2], and total number of "Failure"[in column 2] to be put in column 1 to 3 of summaryTable.
I appreciate any help.

#### HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Last Run</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RL-008</td>
    <td><font color=RED>Failure</font></td>
    <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 03:19:29 AM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>SO-010</td>
    <td><font color=GREEN>Success</font></td>
    <td>Thursday, May 18, 2017 10:44:17 PM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SC-001</td>
    <td><font color=RED>Failure</font></td>
    <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 12:27:31 AM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id=summaryTable>
  <tr>
    <th id="summary">No of Tests</th>
    <th id="summary">No of Failed</th>
    <th id="summary">No of Passed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How are the tables being generated?

Comment: the <font> tag is no longer supported and should be removed from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain & short JS

```js
var passed = document.querySelectorAll('tr td font[color="GREEN"]').length;
var failed = document.querySelectorAll('tr td font[color="RED"]').length
document.getElementById('summary1').innerHTML += (passed+failed) || 0;
document.getElementById('summary2').innerHTML += failed || 0;
document.getElementById('summary3').innerHTML += passed || 0;
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Last Run</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RL-008</td>
    <td><font color=RED>Failure</font></td>
    <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 03:19:29 AM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>SO-010</td>
    <td><font color=GREEN>Success</font></td>
    <td>Thursday, May 18, 2017 10:44:17 PM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SC-001</td>
    <td><font color=RED>Failure</font></td>
    <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 12:27:31 AM
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id=summaryTable>
  <tr>
    <th id="summary1">No of Tests: </th>
    <th id="summary2">No of Failed: </th>
    <th id="summary3">No of Passed: </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to be cleaned up a little bit (removing FONT tag, not using duplicate ID's for "summary" etc), but this should do what you're looking for. If you're using a server side language to loop and render the main table, (PHP, etc) you can get the counts using PHP to render the summary table..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $testTable = $('#myTable');
  var numTests = $('tbody tr', $testTable).length;
  var numFailed = $('tbody tr:contains("Failure")', $testTable).length;
  var numPassed = $('tbody tr:contains("Success")', $testTable).length;

  $('#num-tests').text(numTests);
  $('#failed-tests').text(numFailed);
  $('#passed-tests').text(numPassed);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Last Run</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>RL-008</td>
      <td>
        <font color="RED">Failure</font>
      </td>
      <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 03:19:29 AM
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>SO-010</td>
      <td>
        <font color="GREEN">Success</font>
      </td>
      <td>Thursday, May 18, 2017 10:44:17 PM
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SC-001</td>
      <td>
        <font color="RED">Failure</font>
      </td>
      <td>Friday, May 19, 2017 12:27:31 AM
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="summaryTable">
  <tr>
    <th>No of Tests</th>
    <th>No of Failed</th>
    <th>No of Passed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="num-tests"></td>
    <td id="failed-tests"></td>
    <td id="passed-tests"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your first number will include the heading. This solution also assumes the usage of jQuery. Otherwise it is correct and will receive an upvote from my part if the mentioned nuances are fixed.

Comment: Yes, I did assume the use of jQuery because the question was tagged with jQuery. I'm referencing tbody, so it shouldn't be counting the table headers. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, forget my criticism :)

Comment: Lol, no worries. Constructive criticism is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using plain Javascript you can gather the table, iterate its rows and increase some variables which will hold the needed values.

```
//Getting the original table
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
//Getting the rows of the original table
var rows = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var success = 0;
var failure = 0;
var tests = 0;
for (var rowIndex in rows) {
    //Get the columns
    var columns = rows[rowIndex].getElementsByTagName("td");
    //Let's skip the header
    if (columns.length) {
        //Adjust the values
        tests++;
        if (columns[1].innerText === "Success") success++;
        else if (columns[1].innerText === "Failure") failure++;
    }
}

var target = document.getElementById("summaryTable");
var targetHeadings = target.getElementsByTagName("th");
targetRows[0].innerText = tests;
targetRows[1].innerText = success;
targetRows[2].innerText = failure;
```